# Cannot invoke getGreen() on the Primitive Type int

Tags: java, android, image-processing, colors

So I'm continuing with my app to pick colors out of a picture taken by the user and returning the RGB values. The problem is that when I attempt to get the green value for the color, I get an error saying "cannot invoke getGreen() on the Primitive Type int". Here's the code I wrote:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap(); 
int touchedRGB = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);          
rgbvals.setText("Color Value" + "#" + Integer.toHexString(touchedRGB));
rgbvals.setTextColor(touchedRGB);
int gval = touchedRGB.getgreen();
```

I also attempted to write the final line as

```
    String gval = Integer.toString(touchedRGB).getGreen();
```

But of course getGreen() can only be used on type int. Thanks in advance for the help guys!

Comment: The last time I checked primitives didn't have methods.

Comment: Could you explain this a little further? I've read that before but it really doesn't make sense to me (i'm transitioning from C to Java so some of the finer nuances are a little weird)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the static method [`green`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#green%28int%29) of the [`Color`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) class :

> Return the green component of a color int. This is the same as saying
>   (color >> 8) & 0xFF

`int gval = Color.green(touchedRGB);`

Comment: Yes you did.  Either test your code, or go read the Javadocs.

Comment: @DavidWallace http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html Go read the android doc.

Comment: My apologies.  I had no idea that the android people had added a completely different class called `Color`.  You should probably note in your answer that this has to be `android.graphics.Color`, not `java.awt.Color`.  I will edit MY answer similarly.  Thank you for educating me.

Comment: OK, thanks @ZouZou. My answer is gone.  I've upvoted yours.  I guess I should stay away from Android questions - it's not really Java, in a way.

Answer (score 0):

Error is here:

```
touchedRGB.getgreen();
```

Java compiler try to say that :

Since `int touchedRGB = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);` touchedRGB is primitive data type(it is integer) you can't call a method on primitive data types, they are not objects.